# Classification using GMM:how to use GMM for classification after doing the pca

Tags: matlab, classification, pca, threshold, gmm

Using Matlab, I have a one Healthy data and 7 Faulty data which are composed of 9 variables and after PCA on my healthy data I have got 3 PCs.

Now when I'm projecting the faulty data on the PCs I get overlapping between healthy and faulty data. Now I need to do GMM(gaussian mixture model) to get my data clustered and how to get the threshold, but I don't know to to do so.

Please if anyone can help me it's for my final year project

Comment: I hope you're not waiting for us to do the code for you.... You have any doubt, feel free to ask.

Comment: I'm not waiting for any code I'm just looking for a clarification , thanks for your help anyway